# In PHP, how can I reach my class/public function?

Tags: php

I am working with some php code where I try to reach a class/public function so I can execute a if/else function with the database connected. I have only worked with another php file before (dirname(**FILE**) but I am not sure how I should adjust that code to reach the class/public function immediately now as they are on the same "page"/php file.

```
class ConnectionInfo
{   

    public function GetConnection()
    {

    $this->conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user","pass", "db") or die(mysqli_error($mysql_pekare));

    }
}


$connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
$connectionInfo->GetConnection();

if (!$connectionInfo->conn)
{
    //Connection failed

}

else
{
    //Connection succeded
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to make the variable `$conn` from `ConnectionInfo` public and use it in your object afterwards:

```
class ConnectionInfo {   
    public var $conn = null;    
    public function GetConnection() {
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user","pass", "db") or die(mysqli_error($mysql_pekare));
    }
}
```

And later:

```
if (!$connectionInfo->conn) {
    //Connection failed
}
```

Another would be to `return` the function value in `GetConnection()`.

Comment: @William.John: Glad to be of any help.

Comment: Is this method safe by the way and free from SQL injections? Or is that only a thing if you use forms?

Comment: @William.John: Actually yes insofar as you here only connect to the database. To prevent you from SQL injections use parameter binding and/or PDO.